# Extract written area from the UIImageView

Tags: swift3, uiimageview

So I have UIImageView that I use for the user to write their signature. The UIImageView takes up the entire screen for the user's ease while appending his signature.

I can get and save the image by `UIImageView.image`, but when I check the the saved image it has a lot of *white space*! the signature is small and doesn't take up the whole screen of the device but the saved image takes up the whole screen of the device including the area where there's no writing/signature.

Is there a way to at least crop/trim the image to area where there's signature?

**UPDATE:**
if you look at the sample below you'll notice the area around the signature. I can't resize the image itself when displaying as it will make the signature smaller and harder to read 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found a way myself. What I did is I take note of two `CGPoint` the leftPoint and the rightPoint in `touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`, the following method is use to update the leftPoint and the rightPoint

```
func updatePoints(currentPoint: CGPoint){
    if leftPoint.x > currentPoint.x {
        leftPoint.x = currentPoint.x
    }
    if leftPoint.y > currentPoint.y {
        leftPoint.y = currentPoint.y
    }

    if rightPoint.x < currentPoint.x {
        rightPoint.x = currentPoint.x
    }
    if rightPoint.y < currentPoint.y {
        rightPoint.y = currentPoint.y
    }
}
```

When finally going to save the signature. I calculate the width and the height of the image base on the said points then crop the image using `CGRect()`

```
let width = rightPoint.x - leftPoint.x
let height = rightPoint.y - leftPoint.y
let rect = CGRect(x: leftPoint.x, y: leftPoint.y, width: width, height: height)
let croppedImage = imageView.image!.cropRect(rect)
```

If you have other idea please let me know! for now I'll be using this. Thanks